# How does Time wait for a process that it is timing?

Tags: unix, time

When timing processes with time(1), how does time know when the process has finished executing? Is it done by busy waiting? If so, does it affect the timing accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably using [wait4(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) or [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) which is *not* busy waiting.

Notice that [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) may be a shell builtin (e.g. in [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)). For `/usr/bin/time` you can see using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) that it uses `wait4`

The timing accuracy is given by the kernel. Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Also, [GNU time](https://www.gnu.org/software/time/) (and `bash`, and most of your Linux commands) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so download its source code and study it.